# For what use is this circuit?

Tags: power, filter

I need to power up an IC, but there is no description of reference design. Just an image.

This is the image:

[image]

This is a circuit to add to IC. But i can't understand it's use. Do it provide me a short of voltage stabilization? Do it provide me a power up sequence?

I have no more information that i can provide. Can someone help me to understand electronic function that this circuit provide me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/486/XC6206P152PR-pdf.php) is its datasheet and it is a positive fixed voltage regulator.

Through pin 2 enters a voltage not greater than 6V and on pin 3 it outputs 1.5 V as long as:

- the load doesn't draw more than 250 mA
- the input voltage is with 250 mV greater than the output voltage

See the datasheet for full specifications.

In the schematic you provided, this IC:

- is powered via AVDD with approximately 2.8 V
- the output is available on DVDD

Comment: But if this IC use AVDD pin and DVDD pin as input and output, what influence may have on VDD and DOVDD?

Comment: @Yaro VDD and DOVDD and AVDD have all the same voltage and can be used as inputs. The inductor present between them is for further filtering and most probably, in the original design, those filtered lines supplied other circuitry.

Comment: I'd suspect that VDD2.8 is the input. It is connected by single inductors to each of AVDD and D0VDD and to the regulator.

Comment: I have more questions: - What help provide an inductor in Vin and Vout, a short of noise filter? Can i change voltage regulator and maintain same inductors value? - If i change capacitors value, like from 0.1uF and 10uF to 0.01uF and 2.2uF like i see in other type of power supply of the same module, it change significantly the filter frequencies? - Instead of use 3 inductors, if i use multiple voltage regulators, can replace them with only 1 inductor at the power supply?